# Z3 Solver : Stable version for Java API

Tags: z3

I would like to ask how do I download a stable version of Z3 for using Java API?
In the master branch in `codeplex`, the source does not contain directory `src/api/java`.

This is present in some branches like `cade24` or `rc` and others. 
I do not have an idea which one to choose from. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way at the moment is to use the `unstable` branch. There will be a new master release soon, which will contain exactly what is there for Java right now.

Comment: The new master release happen yesterday (v4.3.2) and the Java API is now also available in the master branch as well as our binary distributions.